# Problems trying to compile a program with external header

Tags: c++, header, g++, mingw

I'm learning c++ and I'm trying to use a library that I've downloaded from internet in my program ( from here https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).
Because I want everything to be quite tidy, I put all the .hh files in a subfolder named "BI".
However when I try to compile my .cpp file with g++ (It's MinGW on Windows XP SP3), the compiler outputs the following error:

`` J:\comp proj\FS>J:\Programmi\MinGW\bin\g++.exe "J:\comp proj\FS\test.cpp" -o "J:\comp proj\FS\test.exe" -I "J:\comp proj\FS\BI"
E:\DOCUME~1\MrJackV\IMPOST~1\Temp\ccidH1Z6.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to BigInteger::BigInteger(int)'
E:\DOCUME~1\MrJackV\IMPOST~1\Temp\ccidH1Z6.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference tooperator<<(std::ostream&, BigInteger const&)'
E:\DOCUME~1\MrJackV\IMPOST~1\Temp\ccidH1Z6.o:test.cpp:(.text$ZNK10BigIntegermlERKS[BigInteger::operator*(BigInteger const&) const]+0x29): undefined reference
to `BigInteger::multiply(BigInteger const&, BigInteger const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status ``

I've tried using the `-I, -l and -L` switches to fix the problem but with no success.
Moreover I've tried in the cpp to put `#include "BI/BigIntegerLibrary.hh"` but that didn't work.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some messing around I figured out that I needed to do a couple of things

1. add the -L switch with the dir of the header files
2. add to the g++ command line all the .cc files (e.g. g++ test.cpp BigInteger.cc etc.)
3. put everything in a batch file for semplicity

wow, now it seems quite easy!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use both -L and -l switches. -L to point to the directory containing the library binary, -l to name that binary

e.g. -L/home/ed/libs -lmath

Comment: Where can I find the library name?

Edit: ld says 'cannot find -lBigIntegerLibrary'

Comment: It is where you installed it. Look for libBigIntegerlibrary.so or libBigIntegerlibrary.a

Comment: There is nothing like that, there are only .hh files, do I have to compile them as well?

Answer (score 0):

There's two keywords to keep in mind.  `Undeclared` means the compiler has never heard of it.  `Undefined` means the compiler has heard of it, but doesn't know exactly how to use it.  For those errors you need to tell it to link with the BigInteger library that should have come with the headers (A *.lib file)  I'm hot sure exactly how gcc includes link libraries (Ed Heal says -L and -l, I'd do that).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't link with the library code.
Read the "README", then follow its advice to adapt the enclosed Makefile.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by "adapting the makefile"?
Edit: Ok, I reread the README and it tells about the makefile. Is there something else I can use to compile the .cc files? (I'm in windows)

Comment: P.S. Can you please link me a tutorial that explains how to do all of this?

Comment: @MrJackV: I didn't know that you were totally unfamiliar with `make`. There's always Visual C++ Express Edition - it can be downloaded for free from Microsoft. I'm not aware of any good tutorials for `make` as such, but googling for "compiling with make" turns up quite a few hits. VC++EE would probably get you going faster, though. And there's probably a gazillion tutorials for it out there.